# Java Spring Framework: структура директорий веб проекта

Tags: java, spring

Посоветуйте структуру директорий для веб проекта на основе **Java Spring Framework**. Проект большой, в нем множество разделов, которые как мне кажется было бы хорошо разделить на модули.

Раннее работал с PHP, использовал паттерн **HMVC** - он был для меня удобен. Где была примерно такая структура директорий:

- application

  - ...
  - modules

    - module1

      - configs
      - controllers
      - models
      - views
    - module2
  - ...

Но, не уверен, что в **Java Spring** подобная структура будет разумной.

Comment: По мне любая упорядоченная структура проекта, сильно лучше чем просто кучка файлов =) А вообще в Java у war(Web application ARchive) есть четкая структура, без котороый, он просто не будет деплоится: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

Comment: @Vartlok а вот конкретно структура директорий исходников (src/*.java). Нету никаких рекомендаций по её организации? Больше интересует что-то типа структуры которую я указал в описании вопроса (для **HMVC**). По скольку проект действительно достаточно большой и в дальнейшем реорганизовывать структуру директорий будет весьма накладно :) Не хотелось бы накосячить изначально.

Comment: *а вот конкретно структура директорий исходников* - начните пользоваться maven-ом для сборки проекта. Он даст вам готовую структуру. Или вас волнует как классы по пакетам раскладывать?